Batch is not updating Account Rank correctly, rank is updating for each scope
My scenario is We have three custom fields in Account object - Closings, LoanAmt, Ranking. Ranking has to be ranked according to Closings amount. When Closings amount is same for couple of accounts, then we have to consider LoanAmt and rank it. I wrote a simple batch class to update Rank. I have inserted 300 records with testdata and executed the batch class with scope as 100. Ranking is happening for every 100 records. so i am getting three records with rank 1 and so on. below is code and please let me know where i went wrong.
global class AccountJVClosingRank_Batch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {
    
    public Integer ranking = 0;
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
            SELECT Id, Name, LoanAmt__c, Closings__c
            FROM Account
            WHERE Record_Type_Name__c = 'JV Partner'
            ORDER BY Closings__c DESC, LoanAmt__c DESC NULLS LAST
        ]);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope) {
        Integer i = 1;

        for(Account ac: scope) {
            ac.ClosingRank__c = i;
            i = i + 1;
        }
        update scope;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        // Any post execute operations can be done in finish method 
    }
}


The execute() method is being called once for each batch in your job.
Since you're always resetting Integer i = 1; in execute(), each batch starts with a ranking of 1 (as you've observed). You need a way to persist the "state" of your ranking between batches.
Each call of execute() is a separate transaction, so a static variable won't work.
You could

use an SObject record to store the state (and you'd query that in each call of execute())
add Database.Stateful to your batch class's implements declaration (e.g. public class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful) to make class variables persist between batches (but I hear this slows down batch processing)
use the org cache (not sure if the session cache would work) to store/retrieve the state, though it's not guaranteed to keep the data in the cache so this is probably a poor choice

The easiest approach would be to use Database.Stateful and use your existing ranking instance variable instead of Integer i within your execute() method.

Thanks Derek, its working now
